# ggplot2 sorting X Axis by start date of timeframes

Tags: r, sorting, ggplot2

My plot is unsolicitedly sorted by alphabetical order on the y axis.

Instead, I need it to be sorted by the starting dates on the x axis.

I tried "reorder" and changing the order of factor levels - without any luck.

How do I sort the plot according to the starting dates of the timeframes on the x axis with the oldest being the first one?

Thanks for any lead!

```
#Dataframe
data <- data.frame(name = c('Alex','Bobby','Chris','Zack'),
                   start = c('20.09.1949','04.10.1982','21.11.2007','28.09.2017'),
                   end = c('29.10.1957','27.10.1998', '28.10.2009','14.03.2018'),
                   Team = c('Right','Wrong','Wrong','Right'))

#Plot 
ggplot(data, aes(x=start, xend=end, y=name, yend=name, color=Team)) +
  geom_segment(size=4) +
  labs(title='Overview', size= 6, x='Tenure', y='Judge') +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c('red', 'black', 'green' , 'grey')) +
  theme_wsj() + 
  theme(axis.title = element_text(),text = element_text(size=5), axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1)) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(lineheight = 2, size = 6))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
#Plot
data %>%
  mutate(start=as.Date(start,'%d.%m.%Y'),
         end=as.Date(end,'%d.%m.%Y'),
         name=factor(name,levels = unique(name),ordered = T)) %>%
  mutate(start=as.character(start),
         end=as.character(end)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=start, xend=end, y=name, yend=name, color=Team)) +
  geom_segment(size=4) +
  labs(title='Overview', size= 6, x='Tenure', y='Judge') +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c('red', 'black', 'green' , 'grey')) +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(),text = element_text(size=12),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1)) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(lineheight = 2, size = 6))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: this works and i guess i was looking for that 

name=factor(name,levels = unique(name),ordered = T)) 


why do you use "mutate" function prior to that?

thx

Comment: @TomTe Hi Tom, I used mutate() to transform the variables in factors so that they can fit properly in your plot. Hope that helped, let me know if the code worked and consider potentially accepting the answer if the solution helped. Glad to always help you!